# Populate checkbox list from enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, enums

I have created a public enum Interests

```
public enum Interests
{
    Sport,
    Party,
    Gaming   
}
```

And wanted to have a List of Enums in my user-Profile

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<Interests> Interests = new List<Interests>;
}
```

I want to create a Checkbox-Form for my Enum-Values, which finally should get stored in my List, but can't find out how ...

I want to have for each Hobby in enum Interests a Checkbox-Field and every checked Checkbox should get stored in the List .

Comment: Be more specific. What checkbox? In ASP Web Forms, ASP MVC, WPF?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use the enum as a [flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a list of them?  It doesn't make sense for a user to have the same interest twice.

Comment: I want to have a checkbox-field for each value of my enum, don?t want to have a List, will check out the flag thy

Comment: This makes no sense. You enum should have the `flags` attribute with `Sport = 1, Party = 2, Gaming = 4` and the you model has `public Interests Interests { get; set; };` (not a list) and then create your checkboxes as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878487/how-to-create-checkboxes-for-enum-type-in-mvc5/31890821#31890821)

Comment: Thy, sounds like the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
checkboxID.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Interests));
checkboxID.DataBind();
```

For MVC:

`@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Interests)` in the view

Comment: Where should I put this code? On the view or the controller?

Comment: Thx, but need Checkboxes instead of the DropDownList, so when the Checkbox us checked the value of the enum get's into my List ;)